# Bash -c command parsing

Tags: bash

The bash manpage states the following for the `-c` option:

> -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string,
> the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the
> shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

From the above I would expect the code below to be equivalent in its output:

```
# or possibly (`bash -c date date +%z`)
$ bash -c date +%z
Wed Oct 18 10:02:47 PM UTC 2023
$ date +%z
+0000
# The first command gives the output of `date` without the format specifier.
```

However, my bash (GNU bash, version 5.2.15) never seems to evaluate additional command line positional parameters. Everything after the first argument after the `-c` option is silently discarded. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the man page.

How would I pass multiple arguments to a `bash -c` command as words (arg vector under the hood) rather than one string (`bash -c "date +%z"`)? Is this possible?

### Context

My goal in asking this question is to understand how bash expects command parameters to be passed in order to correctly feed them into bash via one of the `execve()` family of functions from another program (a wrapper shell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first argument is assigned to $0

$0 is not the first argument, $1 is. Also, you need to use the arguments in the command string.

```
bash -c 'date "$1"' zero +%z
```

Comment: Well _that_ is not what I expected from the manpage description. Thanks.

Comment: @111--- read it as "the first argument [out of 'arguments after the command_string'] is assigned to $0". It's not the first argument to the executed script.

Answer (score 2):

Here,

```
bash -c date +%z
```

The first non-option argument after the `-c` is `date`, that's the shell code that Bash will parse and run. The arguments after that are assigned to the shell or script name `$0` (here, `+%z`), then the positional parameters `$1`, `$2` ... (all unset here).

The string `+%z` is not discarded, but since the command `date` does not make use of `$0` (or `$1` etc.), it does not affect what the shell does. It would get used if the shell had to print an error message, however. E.g.:

```
$ /bin/bash -c datexxx +%z
+%z: datexxx: command not found
```

The script couldn't find the command `datexxx`, so it did output an error message, prefixing it with the name that we gave to the script (`+%z`).

---

To use the arguments that come after `-c` and the shell code, you'll need to pass a command that uses the script name in `$0` or the positional parameters `$1`..., e.g.:

```
% bash -c 'echo "script name: $0", first arg: "$1"' foo bar doo
script name: foo, first arg: bar
```

Though if you want to pass the argument list to another command as-is, you'd rather use `"$@"` (with the quotes) which expands to all positional parameters as distinct fields (as if you'd used `"$1" "$2" ...` for all the set positional parameters).

So (assuming GNU date for `-d`):

```
% bash -c 'date "$@"' my-inline-script +"%F %T" -d '1 Jan 2001'
2001-01-01 00:00:00
```

(Again, that `my-inline-script` goes to `$0` and gets only used if the shell needs to print an error message. The example above should show why it makes sense to put someething descriptive there. In any case, we need to pass some value there as `$0` is filled before the positional parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `-c` needs to be one string.
The rest will be parameters `$0`, `$1`, ...

Example:

```bash
bash -c 'echo name=$0 params=$*' a b c
```

Output: `name=a params=b c`

The use of single quotes is important here. As it does not let the current shell fill in values for `$0`, `$*` etc.

If you wanted to pick up values from the current shell use double quotes. E.g.:

```bash
X=42
bash -c "echo $X"
```

Output: `42`

Mixing single and double quotes is also possible. As long as the argument following `-c` remains one string.

```bash
X=42
bash -c "echo $X"' 0=$0 $*'
```

Output: `42 0=bash`
(here `$0` defaults to `bash`)

Comment: Why this doesn't work here `/bin/bash -c "pp=(1 2 3) && echo ${pp[*]}"` ? Any idea ?

Comment: That doesn't work because the ${pp[*]} is evaluated by the outer shell. Use single quotes to prevent that: /bin/bash -c 'pp=(1 2 3) && echo ${pp[*]}'

Comment: Thanks. That worked.